# Inverse Laplace Transform of $s^n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I want to calculate Inverse Laplace Transform of $s^n$. I have an idea, but I do not know if it works?

We have a formula to compute inverse laplace transforms of functions as below,

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} [ F(s) ] = -\frac{\mathcal{L}^{-1} [ F^{\prime}(s) ]}{t}.$$

So from the given formula, we can obtain

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} [ s ]= -\frac{\mathcal{L}^{-1} [ 1 ]}{t}= -\frac{\delta (t)}{t}.$$
and as a result,
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} [ s^n ] = (-1)^n\frac{n!\delta (t)}{t^n}$$
 Is it right? In fact, I want to know the necessary conditions to use the given formula.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Intuitively, the derivative of the Dirac delta function $\delta'$ has Laplace transform $s$. The derivative of the Dirac delta is a generalized function that pulls out the derivative of the function with a change of sign: for any interval $[a,b]$ where $a < 0 < b$,

$$\int_a^b \delta'(t)f(t) \ dt = \left[ \delta(t) f(t) \right]_a^b - \int_a^b  \delta(t) f'(t) \ dt = -f'(0)$$

Applying that procedure inductively,

$$L^{-1}\{s^n\}(t) =  \delta^{(n)}(t)$$

Comment: This answer is not correct.  The inverse Laplace transform of $s^n$, for non-negative  integer values of $n$ is given by $$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{s^n\}=\delta^{(n)}(t)$$There is no factor of $(-1)^n$.  Note that for $f(t)=e^{-st}$, $(-1)^n \frac{d^n e^{-st}}{dt^n}=s^ne^{-st}$.  I'll edit the sign error accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\left.\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}s^{n}\expo{ts}
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}\,\right\vert_{\ t\ >\ 0} =
\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}s^{n}\expo{ts}{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim} &\
-\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}\pars{-s}^{n}\expo{n\pi\ic}\expo{ts}
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} -
\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}\epsilon^{n}\expo{\ic n\theta}\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} -
\int_{-\epsilon}^{-\infty}\pars{-s}^{n}\expo{-n\pi\ic}\expo{ts}
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\expo{n\pi\ic}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}s^{n}\expo{-ts}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} -
{\epsilon^{n + 1}\sin\pars{n\pi} \over \pars{n + 1}\pi} +
\expo{-n\pi\ic}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}s^{n}\expo{-ts}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{\epsilon^{n + 1}\sin\pars{n\pi} \over \pars{n + 1}\pi} -
{\sin\pars{n\pi} \over \pi}
\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}s^{n}\expo{-ts}\,\dd s
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{\epsilon^{n + 1}\sin\pars{n\pi} \over \pars{n + 1}\pi} -
{\sin\pars{n\pi} \over \pi}\bracks{%
-\,{\epsilon^{n + 1} \over n + 1}\,\expo{-t\epsilon} -
\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}{s^{n + 1} \over n + 1}\expo{-ts}\pars{-t}\,\dd s}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim} &\
-\,{\sin\pars{n\pi} \over \pars{n + 1}\pi}\,t
\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}s^{n + 1}\expo{-ts}\,\dd s
\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\to}
-\,{\sin\pars{n\pi} \over \pars{n + 1}\pi}\,t^{-n - 1}\,\Gamma\pars{n + 2}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{\sin\pars{n\pi} \over \pars{n + 1}\pi}\,t^{-n - 1}\,
{\pi \over \Gamma\pars{-1 - n}\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{n + 2}}} =
-\,{1 \over n + 1}\,t^{-n - 1}\,
{1 \over \Gamma\pars{-n}/\pars{-1 - n}}
\\[5mm] = &
\bbx{\ds{1 \over t^{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{-n}}} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: I feel that you should give some more insights (especially regarding the difference to the answer of Simon S). I guess your result is only valid for $n<0$?