# Inverse Laplace Transform of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform

It seems to me that most distributions (positive, bounded, finite integral, continuous (to some degree)) must have a polynomial Bilateral Laplace transform.  How is this inverted?  Most inverse Laplace transforms seem to rely on poles of function, what if it doesn't have any?

Comment: L[Uniform distribution ,s] = Sin[s]/s, Triangular distribution (Sin[s]/s)^2

Comment: Inverse Laplace Transform of the entire functions are often especially difficult to express in nice form, even they obviously exist. Typical examples including the inverse Laplace Transform of $e^{as^2}$ (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169275) . And the inverse Laplace Transform of $s^n$ for natural number $n$ should express in terms of the derivative of the Dirac delta function (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010927).

Comment: Thanks, so there is no 'standard' mechanism for inverting entire functions, or even polynomials.